# How I order by name the database android studio?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

how I order my sql database by names and not by added entry?

```
newValues.put(PDFDatabaseManager.KEY_VATHMOS, vathmos.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    newValues.put(PDFDatabaseManager.KEY_FIRSTNAME, firstname.getText().toString());
                    newValues.put(PDFDatabaseManager.KEY_SECONDNAME, lastname.getText().toString());


                    long found = database.insert(PDFDatabaseManager.DATABASE_USERS_TABLE, null, newValues);
                    a.dismiss();
                }
            });

            SQLiteDatabase database = context.pdfDatabaseManager.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = database.rawQuery("Select * From " + PDFDatabaseManager.DATABASE_USERS_TABLE + ";", null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` caluse to order the items

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery(
        "Select * From " + PDFDatabaseManager.DATABASE_USERS_TABLE + " ORDER BY " +
                PDFDatabaseManager.KEY_FIRSTNAME + " ASC, " +
                PDFDatabaseManager.KEY_SECONDNAME + " ASC;", null);
```

**N.B:** Use `ASC` for *ascending* order and `DESC` for *descending* order

Answer (score 0):

sqlite queries support `ORDER BY` clause which you can use to sort your result accordingly.

`SELECT * FROM YourTableName ORDER BY tableColumn1 ASC;`